# Pummel [panel]?

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[panel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/panel) is an undefined tag with 42 questions.  Even if it was defined, it begs misuse because it can apply to so many different kinds of things, and people don't read the wiki excerpts.  Should we beat it with a stick until it's dust?

Comment: Feel free to do so.

Comment: I started cleaning up the cases of bad tagging and decoration.  It's not leaving much, anyway.

Comment: OK, the deed is done.